# How to calculate a value among different column in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my project, I have a file.

Some contents of this file is like this:

```
user=bio-zhaoy group=bio-zhaijx queue=gpu start=1551321260 total_execution_slots=12 end=1551370299
user=mse-tangchm group=mse-chengch queue=cal-l start=1551351386 total_execution_slots=96 end=1551372665
user=chem-quanm group=chem-jiangw queue=fat start=1551318056 total_execution_slots=18 end=1551374993
user=cs-likm group=cs-hisao queue=cal-l start=1551341318 total_execution_slots=12 end=1551376362
user=cs-likm group=cs-hisao queue=cal-l start=1551340870 total_execution_slots=12 end=1551379856
user=phy-shizs1 group=phy-shizs1 queue=cal-s start=1551372666 total_execution_slots=96 end=1551380535
user=ose-guoz group=ose-guoz queue=cal-s start=1551380539 total_execution_slots=96 end=1551380546
user=mse-tangchm group=mse-chengch queue=cal-l start=1551351334 total_execution_slots=96 end=1551381367
user=bio-zhaoy group=bio-zhaijx queue=gpu start=1551357949 total_execution_slots=24 end=1551384269
user=mee-xud group=mee-hucz queue=cal-l start=1551184507 total_execution_slots=48 end=1551386704
user=mse-tangchm group=mse-chengch queue=cal-l start=1551351362 total_execution_slots=96 end=1551388501
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551129996 total_execution_slots=36 end=1551389224
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551129996 total_execution_slots=36 end=1551389224
user=maad-zhoukc group=maad-wanmp queue=fat start=1551336869 total_execution_slots=144 end=1551391828
user=maad-liuzj group=maad-chensy queue=ser start=1551323808 total_execution_slots=1 end=1551392934
user=maad-liuzj group=maad-chensy queue=ser start=1551323868 total_execution_slots=1 end=1551392989
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551134144 tot al_execution_slots=36 end=1551393349
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551134144 total_execution_slots=36 end=1551393354
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551134144 total_execution_slots=36 end=1551393376
user=phy-shaoxj group=phy-wangkd queue=cal-l start=1551134144 total_execution_slots=120 end=1551393380
user=maad-linys group=maad-wanmp queue=cal-l start=1551134144 total_execution_slots=36 end=1551393385
user=chem-wangyg group=chem-wangyg queue=cal-l start=1551324604 total_execution_slots=48 end=1551394118
user=mee-xud group=mee-z queue=cal-l start=1551254511 total_execution_slots=48 end=1551397837
user=mse-xiaow group=mse-g queue=fat start=1551358601 total_execution_slots=90 end=1551398698
user=phy-liugw group=phyd queue=cal-l start=1551352409 total_execution_slots=360 end=1551400256
user=mee-xud group=mee-huz queue=cal-l start=1551310151 total_execution_slots=48 end=1551400565
user=mse-xiaow group=mse-l queue=fat start=1551400769 total_execution_slots=90 end=1551401158
```

Now, i want to calculate the time value for every row.
The calculate method is:

```
(end-start)*total_execution_slots
```

For example with first line:

```
(1551370299-1551321260)*12
```

I need to solve in bash shell. I want to take the calculated value as the 
 last column.

I have tried:

```
for i in $(cat file)
do
 starttime=`awk '{print $4}' $i | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`
 endtime=`awk '{print $6}' $i | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`
 slots=`awk '{print $5}' $i | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`
 totaltime=($endtime-$starttime)*$slots
 echo $i" "$totaltime >> resultinfo
done
```

But it is hung, when i am running this script

who can help me?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `awk -F'[ =]' '{print ($12-$8)*$10}' file`

Comment: @oguzismail, that is great, thank you very much

Comment: @stack : Be aware that the solution by oguzismail will break if the order of the fields changes or if additional fields are inserted. In a more stable solution, you would explicitly look up the names (`start` for instance). This also would be better for maintenance than relying on field numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code :

```
while read -r val_user val_group val_queue val_start val_total_execution_slots val_end; do 
{
  num_val_start=$(echo $val_start | cut -d'=' -f 2)
  num_val_end=$(echo $val_end | cut -d'=' -f 2)
  num_val_total_execution_slots=$(echo $val_total_execution_slots | cut -d'=' -f 2)
  awaited_res=$(( ( $num_val_end - $num_val_start ) * $num_val_total_execution_slots ))
  echo $awaited_res
}
done < yourfile
```

you should replace yourfile by the name of your file and it will provide the result of the operation. You can shorten the script but I preferred to use variables to keep it clear. The first part read the content of the file in several variables which are processed by taking just the value after '=' character. Then the $(( allow to get the result of the expr command to process the formula you wanted.